Could "Is there a such thing as collective narcissism?" be modified or asked again in a different form such that it could be answered?
I ran across Is there a such thing as collective narcissism? by accident just now and my first thought was

hmm... yes sure, something at least analogous to it, and something like this surely has been written about somewhere.

but I can see that it might be a challenge to refactor this to be on-topic here. There is an answer that cites a work that includes the term "national vanity" but it seems that this is more along the lines of sociology or politics than psychology.
I then typed "group" into the tag search box and found no results, so I wonder if the questions in this site that are about psychology are limited to the psychology of individuals as opposed to group dynamics or crowd psychology.
I do see that there is a [tag: wisdom-of-crowds] and while it only has two questions, they are both very well received and answered, probably because they are well written and well researched.

Appropriate metric(s) for quantifying the accuracy gain obtained from averaging dyads of estimates instead of adopting individual estimates?
Performance of a group solving a cognitive task: How does it scale?

Narrow question: Could "Is there a such thing as collective narcissism?" be modified or asked again in a different form such that it could be answered?
Broader question: Are questions about group dynamics or crowd psychology in general a good or poor fit for this site? Provided they are well constructed and researched questions, are these within the scope of the site>
In the main meta from 9 years ago, answer(s) to Politics (science, sociology, theory of) questions should go where? sort-of point to Politics SE, and I think that folks in History SE sometimes like to write answers about why a leader or group or country ended up doing something in the past, and Philosophy SE has [96 questions tagged sociology, but in this meta question I'm only asking about the scope of this site.

First off: group dynamics/crowd psychology is definitely on topic here.
In regards to the specific question, note that it was closed for the following reason:

Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers.

As you indicate, this seems to be the primary difference with other questions which were not closed.

Could "Is there a such thing as collective narcissism?" be modified or
asked again in a different form such that it could be answered?

Yes. But, given that it will require additional specification of the question (including initial research), it will probably end up being a different/more precise question. E.g., it could link to a specific definition of narcissism, clarifying how the OP understands it, and better ask/relate how it could apply to a collective.
Therefore, rather than presuming a question on behalf of the OP, I think you are better asking your own more specific form of it as a new question in case you are interested. This is the downside of unclear questions: only the OP really knows what they find interesting/are asking.

a thorough and helpful answer. Yes closed question "archaeolog/refactoring" is unwise here and probably in general. Thanks!
